# Int Size Bytes Socket AS3

Tags: java, actionscript-3, sockets

I have Java Socket sending .TXT file ( 10 MB ) . But the AS3 only gets 63 Kb . I do not understand the loss of bytes ...

( Server ) Java Source Socket. Send File To Client AS3

```
    public void sendFile(String fileName) {
        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);


        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();


        byte[] fileSize = intToByte(mybytearray.length);
        byte[] clientData = new byte[(int) myFile.length() + mybytearray.length];
        System.arraycopy(fileSize, 0, clientData, 0, fileSize.length);  
        System.arraycopy(mybytearray, 0, clientData, 4, mybytearray.length);  


        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.write(clientData, 0, clientData.length);
        dos.flush(); }
```

Client/Receive Bytes AS3 From Java

```
private function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void {
var file:File;
var fs:FileStream;
var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("tmpReceive.txt");
fs = new FileStream();
fs.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,onCloseFileReceive);


if(_socket.bytesAvailable > 0) {
  while(_socket.bytesAvailable) {

 _socket.readBytes(fileData,0,0);
  } }

  fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);


   fs.writeBytes(fileData);
   fs.close();  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says "Socket receives data asynchronously" [in the `flash.net.Socket` manual](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html), this means that you have to listen for events on that socket and while there are events, you read bytes from socket, and once you receive "close" event or discover the end of file by any other means, only then you will be able to flush the file to disk. I see that you first send a 4-byte integer value that contains the file size, so use this value to determine if the file is fully read through the socket.

```
var fileSize:int=0;
var fileData:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
_socket.addEventListener(flash.events.ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA,readFromSocket);
function readFromSocket(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    if (_socket.bytesAvailable==0) return; // no data
    if (fileSize==0) {
        fileSize=_socket.readInt(); 
        // get file size if we've just initialized file transfer
        fileData.length=0;
        fileData.position=0; // clear the array to not mess with previous file, if any
    } else if (fileSize==fileData.length) return; // still flushing file to disk
    if (_socket.bytesAvailable>0) {
        _socket.readBytes(fileData,0,Math.min(fileSize-fileData.length,_socket.bytesAvailable)); 
        // get all available bytes up to received file's length
        // there might not be enough, so we use minimum of what's unread and what's present
        if (fileData.length>=fileSize) {
            trace("File received: size given",fileSize","size received", fileData.length); 
            // these should be equal, if not, you have more to dig
            // now dump the file, you have the code, insert it here
            // and don't forget to set fileSize to 0 once you have received 
            // the "end of writing file to disk" event, so that you can
            // receive another file via same socket
            // once you'll perfect this, consider sending an UTF-string
            // with file name prior to sending file.
        }
    }
}
```

Your 63kb value seemingly is 64kb less some bytes for socket service, which generate one event of `ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA` for the app to read, while you are assuming that all 10MB of data is put into the socket at once.

Comment: Hi Vesper! (Y) Thanks for your help ! But the stranger that the Socket AS3 , says fileSize 126221071 (Size From Server ) source: fileSize _socket.readInt = (); to receive the bytes in the source: if ( _socket.bytesAvailable > 0) {
_socket.readBytes ( fileData , 0 , fileSize - fileData.length ) ; an exception occurs : Error : Error # 2030 : End of file was encountered .
at flash.net::Socket/readBytes ()

My Java Socket , sending 4 bytes ( file size ) after the bytes to be read by AS3

Comment: You should send length before data, because otherwise the receiving end does not know a thing about how much data it's about to receive.

Comment: You say I send the size of Bytes ? after sending the file? Is that it? That before the DataOutputStream ( Bytes File) . Sorry, but ... I'm hot head with it. = D

Comment: Hmm, this means the third parameter should remain at 0... or one has to play tricks. Okay, see updated post.

Comment: Hi Vesper...I put this code ( copied stackoverflow ) , and I could write ! tested 135 MB file! downloaded 130 MB ! Almost there ...

Comment: Source Code : if(fileSizeCounter == 0) {
    var len:int = _socket.bytesAvailable
    _socket.readBytes(fileData, 0, len);
    //var str:String = fileData.readMultiByte(len, ISO_CS)
    trace("File total size" + fileData.length);
   
    fs.writeBytes(fileData);
     
    
    trace( "File successefully\nreceived!" );
     
    
   }